# Force focus to TextEdit in ListView

Tags: listview, focus, qml, qtquick2, textedit

Consider following example.

```
Rectangle {
    height: 200
    width: 200
    ListView {
        id: lv
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                name: "aaa"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "bbb"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "ccc"
            }
        }
        delegate: TextEdit {
            id: delegate
            text: name
            width: 200
            height: 100
            activeFocusOnPress: false
            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if(activeFocus) {
                    font.italic = true;
                } else {
                    font.italic = false;
                }
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onDoubleClicked : {
                    delegate.focus = true;
                    lv.currentIndex = index;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to activate TextEdit by double click. If it's outside of list view it works as expected, but in list view it doe's not work.
I guess the problem is that list view is focus scope, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit [`forceActiveFocus`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#forceActiveFocus-method-2):

> This method sets focus on the item and **ensures that all ancestor FocusScope objects** in the object hierarchy **are also given focus**.

You can either use the overloaded version (without parameters) or the one with a [`FocusReason`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusReason-enum). Here is the modified version of your code using the latter. I've also made two small adjustments with an explanatory comment:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                name: "aaa"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "bbb"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "ccc"
            }
        }
        delegate: TextEdit {
            text: name
            // In the delegate you can access the ListView via "ListView.view"
            width: ListView.view.width  
            height: 50
            activeFocusOnPress: false
            // directly bind the property to two properties (also saving the brackets)
            onActiveFocusChanged: font.italic = activeFocus

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onDoubleClicked : {
                    parent.forceActiveFocus(Qt.MouseFocusReason)
                    parent.ListView.view.currentIndex = index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```